# How to fix footer overlapping with section

Tags: html, css

I am new to web development and design. I am trying to create a website with a navbar 3 section and a footer. Everything works fine but the footer is overlapping with the last section. I can't figure out why. I have tried replacing the section with a div but still, it doesn't help. I even tested the HTML on HTML validator. I don't know what I did wrong here. This is my HTML code:

```
<% layout('boilerplate/boilerplate.ejs') %>
<div class="main-cont">
  <section class="first-cont">
    <%-include('../partials/navbar')%>
    <div class="company-info">
      <div class="intro-cont">
        <div class="intro intro-text">
          <h2>Kick Start Your <br />Company’s Online <br />Journey With Us</h2>
          <p>
            Take advantage of our services and solutions designed to meet all of
            your requirements and take your company online.
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="intro intro-img">
          <img src="/images/artimage.png" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="clients">
        <h2>Our Clients</h2>
        <div class="client-logo">
          <img src="/images/client1.png" alt="" />
          <img src="/images/client2.png" alt="" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="second-cont">
    <h2 id="solution">Our Solutions</h2>
    <div class="pricing-cont">
      <div class="pricing">
        <div class="pricing-img">
          <img src="/images/smallbusiness.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="pricing-des">
          <h2>Small Business</h2>
          <p>Website <br />Web Hosting <br />Domain</p>
          <h2><sup>RM</sup>600</h2>
          <button class="btn btn-info">Get It</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="pricing">
        <div class="pricing-img">
          <img src="/images/mediumbuisness.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="pricing-des">
          <h2>Medium Business</h2>
          <p>
            Website or App<br />Web Hosting<br />Domain<br />Logos & Images<br />Google
            Business Integration
          </p>
          <h2><sup>RM</sup>600</h2>
          <button class="btn btn-info">Get It</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="pricing">
        <div class="pricing-img">
          <img src="/images/largecompany.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="pricing-des">
          <h2 style="margin-bottom: 2px">Enterprise</h2>
          <p style="margin-bottom: 5px; font-size: 12px">
            Website & App<br />Web Hosting<br />Domain<br />Logos & Images<br />Google
            Business Integration<br />System Maintain
          </p>
          <h2 style="margin-top: 10px"><sup>RM</sup>600</h2>
          <button class="btn btn-info">Get It</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="third-cont">
    <div class="whyus whyus-des blue">
      <h2 class="text-white display-4 font-weight-bold">Why Choose Us</h2>
      <p class="text-white lead">
        Our team cares about all the clients <br />
        no matter how big or small. The drives us <br />
        to provide fanatical support to our clients. <br />
        We provide our clients with the best in class <br />
        services as per their needs and demands
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="whyus whyus-img">
      <img src="/images/img1.jpeg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="whyus whyus-img">
      <img src="/images/img2.jpeg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="whyus whyus-des orange">
      <p class="text-white lead">
        We can prove and show how we <br />
        deliver peace of mind, Less Downtime <br />
        and Faster problem solutions for your company
      </p>
      <button class="btn btn-info text-white">Contact Us</button>
    </div>
  </section>
  <div class="footer">

  </div>


</div>
```

and this is my css:

```
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.navbar{
   padding: 10px;
    background: #ffffff;
}
.navbar-collapse{
   margin-left: 30%;
}
.navbar-collapse > button{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    
    color: #ffffff;
}

.nav-link{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    margin-right: 20px;
    
    width: 100px;
}
.first-cont{
    height: 100vh;
}
.company-info{
    background: url("/images/background1.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height:90%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
 .intro-cont{
    width: 90%;
    background-color: #ffffff90;
    margin: 0 auto;
   height: 80%;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.intro-text >h2{
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 500;
    color: #DC604B;
    font-size: 50px;
    transition: font-size 0.8s;
}
.intro-img{
    width: 70%;
    transition: width 0.8s;

}
.intro-img>img{
    width: 100%;
}
.clients{
    
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #ffffff;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.5fr 1fr;
  
}
.clients >h2{
 margin: 10px;
 display: flex;
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
 font-weight: 500;
 color: #DC604B;
 padding: 20px;

}
.client-logo {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    padding: 10px;
    width: 60%;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
}
.client-logo >img{
    width: 30%;
    margin: 10px;
}
.second-cont{
    background:url("/images/background2.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}
.second-cont>h2{
font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
font-weight: 500;
font-size: 45px;
color: #DC604B;
padding: 40px;
}
.pricing-cont{
    display: flex;
    width: 90%;
    flex-direction: row;
    margin: 0 auto;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 80%;
    

}
.pricing{
    background-color: #ffffff;
    margin: 10px;
    width: 28%;
    border-radius: 20px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.2);
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: space-evenly;

   
}
.pricing-img > img{
    width: 100%;
}
.pricing-des{
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    
}
.pricing-des >h2,p{
    font-family: 'Sen',sans-serif;
    color: #372B7B;
}

.pricing-des>p{
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 20px;
}
.pricing-des>h2{
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}



.third-cont{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(2,1fr);
    
}
.whyus{
    background-color: #DC604B;
    width: 100%;
   
    
}
.blue{
    background-color: #48B9FF;
}

.whyus-des{
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.whyus-img>img{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    
}
.whyus >h2,p{
     font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
     
}
.footer{
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: white;
}
```

please help me figure it out! Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Footer goes outside `<div class="main-cont">` not inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the `100vh` in the CSS for the class `.second-cont`. If you either remove it or change it to `100%` it should fix your issue.

To understand more about what `vh` does please go through https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length

[image]

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
  padding: 10px;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.navbar-collapse {
  margin-left: 30%;
}

.navbar-collapse>button {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
}

.nav-link {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  margin-right: 20px;
  width: 100px;
}

.first-cont {
  height: 100vh;
}

.company-info {
  background: url("/images/background1.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 90%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.intro-cont {
  width: 90%;
  background-color: #ffffff90;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 80%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 20px;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.intro-text>h2 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #DC604B;
  font-size: 50px;
  transition: font-size 0.8s;
}

.intro-img {
  width: 70%;
  transition: width 0.8s;
}

.intro-img>img {
  width: 100%;
}

.clients {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 0.5fr 1fr;
}

.clients>h2 {
  margin: 10px;
  display: flex;
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  color: #DC604B;
  padding: 20px;
}

.client-logo {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 60%;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  align-items: center;
}

.client-logo>img {
  width: 30%;
  margin: 10px;
}

.second-cont {
  background: url("/images/background2.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.second-cont>h2 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 500;
  font-size: 45px;
  color: #DC604B;
  padding: 40px;
}

.pricing-cont {
  display: flex;
  width: 90%;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 0 auto;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 80%;
}

.pricing {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  margin: 10px;
  width: 28%;
  border-radius: 20px;
  box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.2);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.pricing-img>img {
  width: 100%;
}

.pricing-des {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.pricing-des>h2,
p {
  font-family: 'Sen', sans-serif;
  color: #372B7B;
}

.pricing-des>p {
  font-size: 15px;
  margin: 20px;
}

.pricing-des>h2 {
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.third-cont {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
}

.whyus {
  background-color: #DC604B;
  width: 100%;
}

.blue {
  background-color: #48B9FF;
}

.whyus-des {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.whyus-img>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.whyus>h2,
p {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

.footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-cont">
  <section class="first-cont">
      <div class="company-info">
        <div class="intro-cont">
          <div class="intro intro-text">
            <h2>Kick Start Your <br />Company’s Online <br />Journey With Us</h2>
            <p>
              Take advantage of our services and solutions designed to meet all of your requirements and take your company online.
            </p>
          </div>
          <div class="intro intro-img">
            <img src="/images/artimage.png" alt="" />
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="clients">
          <h2>Our Clients</h2>
          <div class="client-logo">
            <img src="/images/client1.png" alt="" />
            <img src="/images/client2.png" alt="" />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  </section>

  <section class="second-cont">
    <h2 id="solution">Our Solutions</h2>
    <div class="pricing-cont">
      <div class="pricing">
        <div class="pricing-img">
          <img src="/images/smallbusiness.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="pricing-des">
          <h2>Small Business</h2>
          <p>Website <br />Web Hosting <br />Domain</p>
          <h2><sup>RM</sup>600</h2>
          <button class="btn btn-info">Get It</button>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="pricing">
        <div class="pricing-img">
          <img src="/images/mediumbuisness.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="pricing-des">
          <h2>Medium Business</h2>
          <p>
            Website or App<br />Web Hosting<br />Domain<br />Logos & Images<br />Google Business Integration
          </p>
          <h2><sup>RM</sup>600</h2>
          <button class="btn btn-info">Get It</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="pricing">
        <div class="pricing-img">
          <img src="/images/largecompany.png" alt="" />
        </div>
        <div class="pricing-des">
          <h2 style="margin-bottom: 2px">Enterprise</h2>
          <p style="margin-bottom: 5px; font-size: 12px">
            Website & App<br />Web Hosting<br />Domain<br />Logos & Images<br />Google Business Integration<br />System Maintain
          </p>
          <h2 style="margin-top: 10px"><sup>RM</sup>600</h2>
          <button class="btn btn-info">Get It</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

  <section class="third-cont">
    <div class="whyus whyus-des blue">
      <h2 class="text-white display-4 font-weight-bold">Why Choose Us</h2>
      <p class="text-white lead">
        Our team cares about all the clients <br /> no matter how big or small. The drives us <br /> to provide fanatical support to our clients. <br /> We provide our clients with the best in class <br /> services as per their needs and demands
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="whyus whyus-img">
      <img src="/images/img1.jpeg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="whyus whyus-img">
      <img src="/images/img2.jpeg" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div class="whyus whyus-des orange">
      <p class="text-white lead">
        We can prove and show how we <br /> deliver peace of mind, Less Downtime <br /> and Faster problem solutions for your company
      </p>
      <button class="btn btn-info text-white">Contact Us</button>
    </div>
  </section>
  <div class="footer">

  </div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set all sections style `height: 100vh;`  to `min-height: 100vh;`